# JavaScript Redirect to Page Another website based on URL

Tags: javascript, url

Using JavaScript, how can I make it redirect to another site based on the URL?
(Example)
If someone goes to https://example.com/12345, it will redirect them to https://example.net/12345.
And if someone goes to https://example.com/abc123456, it will redirect them to https://example.net/abc123456

How can I do this?

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question. Are you saying if someone opens a new tab and goes to a web address, or if someone clicks something on your website, or what. Could you show what code you have tried or give a more detailed question so I can get a better understanding of your question? I just want to help to the best of my abilities. Hope to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the place that you have hosted that domain, See if you can find something that makes it a single page app or a way to rewrite all urls to one page so that it doesn't show 404 not found. (not certain how you can do that, I only done it with firebase hosting, it has a way of configuring it so that no matter what url you give it, it always shows you the same page, and also the url doesn't get changed ) if you can do that, this is the code you need:

```
let pathname = location.pathname //if the url is https://example.net/1234,  the path name will be /1234

location.href = "https://example.net" + pathname //if you add that to this string, it would be https://example.net/1234
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for that:

location.href = 'https://example.net/12345';

location.href = 'https://example.net/abc123456';

Or used following code for that:

location.replace('https://example.net/12345');

location.replace('https://example.net/abc123456');

Comment: I need it to work for all URLs though; not just the two mentioned, and I don’t have time to go through every possible ending the the URL and add it to the webpage.